# How can I convert my array into a different array format?

Tags: php, arrays

I want to convert this array

```
[
  {
     "name": "james",
     "age": "42",
     "position": "teacher",
  },
  {
     "name": "lara",
      "age": "34",
     "position": "officer",
  }
]
```

into this array

```
{
  "data": [
    [
      "james",
      "42",
      "teacher",
    ],
    [
      "lara",
      "34",
      "officer",
    ]
  ]
}
```

I tested  `$new = array_values($old);` but this is doing something totally weired:

```
array(15) {
    [0] => array(9) {
        "james" ["name"] => string(19)
        "42" ["age"] => string(18)
        "teacher" ["position"] => string(17)
  ....
```

Comment: What language are you using? Looks like PHP, but didn't want to assume.

Comment: Oh sorry, totally forgot. Yes php

Comment: so you are parsing JSON array of objects into PHP array. What you tried so far. Show the code.

Comment: I updated my question with the code I tried

Comment: Is your input a JSON string, or is it already a PHP array?

Comment: my input is an php array

Comment: I think you are going to regret doing that later. Associative arrays are good stuff.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were on the right track with `array_values`, but you need to apply it to every element of your original array rather than running it once for the whole thing. You can either do that in a loop, or by running it through a function such as `array_map`.

You can then assign the result of that into a new array, under your `data` key:

```
$new = [
  'data' => array_map('array_values', $old),
];
```

See https://eval.in/874380

Answer (score 1):

you need foreach

```
$array = array(
    array("name" => "james","age" => 25),
    array("name" => "joy","age" => 32)
);

$newArray = [];

foreach($array as $key => $a){
  $newArray['data'][$key][0] = $a["name"];
  $newArray['data'][$key][1] = $a["age"];
}
```